# What is the purpose of using label_replace when it's discarded by means of a `without` operator?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm following [this article here](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/23/anomaly-detection-using-prometheus/) and there's a part where the author adds a label, but this label is immediately discarded by the surrounding query function. Here is the code:

```
- record: job:http_requests:rate5m_prediction
  expr: >
   quantile(0.5,
     label_replace(
       avg_over_time(job:http_requests:rate5m[4h] offset 166h)
       + job:http_requests:rate5m:avg_over_time_1w - job:http_requests:rate5m:avg_over_time_1w offset 1w
       , "offset", "1w", "", "")
     or
     label_replace(
       avg_over_time(job:http_requests:rate5m[4h] offset 334h)
       + job:http_requests:rate5m:avg_over_time_1w - job:http_requests:rate5m:avg_over_time_1w offset 2w
       , "offset", "2w", "", "")
     or
     label_replace(
       avg_over_time(job:http_requests:rate5m[4h] offset 502h)
       + job:http_requests:rate5m:avg_over_time_1w - job:http_requests:rate5m:avg_over_time_1w offset 3w
       , "offset", "3w", "", "")
   )
   without (offset)
```

According to my understanding, the instant vectors are going to be concatenated by the `or` operator, and then their labels are going to be combined, only for the `offset` label to be discarded (by the `without` operator). Wouldn't it be the same to omit the `label_replace` function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting the definition of the `or` operator on PromQL:

> `vector1 or vector2` results in a vector that contains all original elements (label sets + values) of vector1 and additionally all elements of vector2 which do not have matching label sets in vector1.

So, that label is added to concatenate the results. Otherwise, they would be ignored since all vectors would have matching label sets.

Then, aggregation operations can safely ignore this label, whose sole purpose was to enable concatenation.

Maybe the label name could be improved by making its purpose more explicit. Something along the lines of `im_only_here_to_enable_vector_concatenation` :).